# Appcelerator Titanium Android Intent Crashes Intagram

Tags: android, android-intent, appcelerator-titanium

I'm working with the latest version of appcelerator and am trying to launch instagram with an image selected from the gallery.  Here's my code:

```
  Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
            success:function(event) {                    

            var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
                action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
                type:"image/*"
            });
            intent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, [event.media.nativePath]);          
            var share = Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(intent, 'Sending image to');
            Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(share);

            }
        });
```

Here's the DDMS error:

```
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #3
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): Process: com.instagram.android, PID: 7517
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at android.support.v4.content.j.done(SourceFile:137)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: uri
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:60)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:694)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at com.instagram.creation.photo.crop.au.k(SourceFile:64)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at com.instagram.creation.photo.crop.au.j(SourceFile:28)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at android.support.v4.content.e.b(SourceFile:3242)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at android.support.v4.content.i.call(SourceFile:123)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-10 08:03:02.957: E/AndroidRuntime(7517):     ... 3 more
08-10 08:03:02.987: E/android.os.Debug(3602): ro.product_ship = true
08-10 08:03:02.987: E/android.os.Debug(3602): ro.debug_level = 0x4f4c
08-10 08:03:02.997: E/android.os.Debug(3602): sys.mobilecare.preload = false
```

This code crashes or does not present the image with everything except Facebook.  For Facebook the code works as expected.

Comment: in logs it is saying that uri that you are passing is null, you can add a null check before using it.

Comment: The problem is that I'm working in appcelerator javascript, and I'm doing what they document as the correct way to pass the URI.  So adding a check may or may not help.

Answer (score 0):

I found some example code that works, it can be found here

https://gist.github.com/ricardoalcocer/6323964